# Cant get object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  ...
end


class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :cars
  ...
end
```

Car controller:

```
  def index
     @title = "All cars"
     @cars = Car.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end
```

View:

```
<%= car.manufacturer.name %>
```

Shows: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Ok. View:

```
<%= car.manufacturer[name] %>
```

Shows: undefined local variable or method `name' for #<#:0x460c488>

BUT! View:

```
<%= car.manufacturer.to_yaml %>
```

Shows:

```
--- !ruby/object:Manufacturer
attributes:
  id: 1
  name: Acura
  created_at: 2011-11-30 09:59:19.750976000 Z
  updated_at: 2011-12-06 10:38:46.569531000 Z
```

So how can i read name of Car.manufacturer?

Comment: You have `belongs_to :model`, not `belongs_to :manufacturer`. Is that a transcription error?

Comment: fixed, thx. car have both: model and manufacturer

Comment: `car.manufacturer[name]` is wrong anyway, you probably want `car.manufacturer[:name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= car.manufacturer.name if car.manufacturer  %>` as some results will not have the attribute set, this ensures you only call the attribute getter method if it has been set.

Comment: at least it says Manufacturer now. It's probably because of paginate. Get rid of paginate and see what happens when you try different ways to reference it then.

Comment: found! it works with: <%= car.manufacturer.name unless car.manufacturer.nil? %> So some Cars in Database have no manufacturer_id. Solution was soooo simple :)

Comment: nice one, updated my answer with better syntax *perhaps* (off the top of my head)... well done, didn't think of that!

Comment: Please do not post such short answers. Explain the reason why this works. That way, questioners go away with a better understanding of why this worked, rather than just the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= car.manufacturer.try(:name) %>
```

And you could be interested in [Presenter pattern](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch)